# Getting a seperate token for API calls after already logging in using Msal

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

So here's the best way to explain what i'm needing.

I've built an app that will use our company's AD to login, thus getting a token. I am then supposed to use this app token to call into a shared API (also secured by azure AD) to recieve an API token to make the calls to the api.

I'm using msal and msal-angular npm packages.

Where/How do I go about doing this?

I feel like i'm supposed to be accomplishing this somewhere in a custom interceptor so that i can recieve/add tokens to all my outgoing api calls but this would be my first time messing with interceptors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!